# What does the Suvarna Gharma Anuvaka of the Taittiriya Aranyaka mean?

Tags: vedas, bhagavata-purana, translation-request, uddhava-gita

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3755/36), the Srimad Bhagavatam contains the Uddhava Gita, a discourse similar to the Bhagavad Gita between Krishna and his relative Uddhava on the proper way to live one's life.  And in the course of telling Uddhava how to worship him in idol form, Krishna says [this](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/27/30-31):

> The worshiper should bathe the Deity every day, as opulently as his assets permit, using waters scented with sandalwood, uśīra root, camphor, kuṅkuma and aguru. He should also chant various Vedic hymns, such as the **anuvāka known as Svarṇa-gharma**, the Mahāpuruṣa-vidyā, the Puruṣa-sūkta and various songs of the Sāma Veda, such as the Rājana and the Rohiṇya.

In [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3755/36) I asked about the Mahapurusha Vidya, but now I'm interested in the Suvarna Gharma Anuvaka.  [This book](http://books.google.com/books?id=NkDn2QmGY-YC&lpg=PA254&dq=%22mahapurusa%20vidya%22&pg=PA254#v=onepage&q&f=false) claims that the hymn is lost, but I found it in the Taittiriya Aranyaka of the Yajur Veda (see Anuvaka 3-11-1 on page 50 of [this PDF](http://www.sanskritweb.net/yajurveda/ta-find.pdf)):

> suvarnam gharmam pariveda venam |
>
> indrasyatmanam dashadh carantam |
>
> antassamudre manasa carantam |
>
> brahma'nvavindaddashahotaramarne |
>
> antaha pravishtashasta jananam |
>
> ekassanbahudha vicaraha |
>
> shatam shukrani yatraikam bhavanti |
>
> sarve veda yatraikam bhavanti |
>
> sarve hotaro yatraikaM bhavanti |
>
> sa manasana atma jananam ||

My question is, what does this hymn mean?  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a complete translation of the Taittiriya Aranyaka.  There is [this translation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8120808681) of chapter 5, which deals with the Pravargya ritual.  And there are numerous translations of chapter 7-9, which constitute the Taittirya Upanishad, and of chapter 10, which is the Mahanarayana Upanishad.  But are there any translations of chapter 3, where this hymn is found?

Answer (score 1):

"sarve vedā yatraikaṃ bhavanti" means "where all the Vedas become one".

---

The rest is incomplete. I'm not an expert. I've just collected references for now; will come back and try to make sense of it later.

First, the text itself, from Taittirīya-Āraṇyaka, Prapāṭhaka (=Praśna?) 3, Anuvāka 11. [In Roman script](http://www.sanskritweb.net/yajurveda/ta-find.pdf) and [in Devanagari script](http://www.sanskritweb.net/yajurveda/ta-deva.pdf):

[image: Roman script]
[image: Devanagari script]

The commentary by Sāyaṇācārya (Sāyaṇa-bhāṣya) is available [here](https://archive.org/details/Anandashram_Samskrita_Granthavali_Anandashram_Sanskrit_Series). The same commentary (same scan even), and also the commentary of Bhatta Bhaskara, are available [here](https://archive.org/details/taittiriya). See the bottom right of [this page](https://archive.org/stream/taittiriya/taittiriya_aranyaka_sayana_01#page/n181/mode/2up), and the bottom left of [this page](https://archive.org/stream/taittiriya/taittiriya_aranyaka_bhaskara_01#page/n277/mode/2up).

Comment: Thanks!  I look forward to seeing your attempt to make sense of it.