# What was the purpose of the Kurukshetra war of Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, war, kurukshetra, duryodhana

The Kurushethra war was to bring back Dharma by killing Duryodhana. But what was the need of it?
Duryodhana would have anyways died after few years like any human, right?
Is such a destructive war required to kill him?

Comment: Questions that ask for opinions are not allowed on this forum. Please read the forum rules...

Comment: Duryodhana destiny was to die in the war and this war was already destined to happen. It exactly went as per destiny of Duryodhana actions and Universally planned epic.

Comment: so can I delete this question?

Comment: Wars never happen to kill someone...war happen on some other topic...Ravan refused to return Sita, war happened... Duryodhana refused to return Pandavas kingdom even he  refused to give them 5 villages hence war happened...Check chapters where Krishna goes as piece messsenger... and in Ramayana Angada....now if someone take someone's home then what should be done? Wait for his death?

Comment: @YDS I think it would be wise to do :)it is better  than a war

Comment: @Akash.B you want this sentence to be true always then..'The world suffers a lot. Not because the violence of bad people. But because of the silence of the good people.'...and that's why this Q should be closed as Opinion based...diff people diff opinions...

Comment: @YDS you can close it!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why didn't Kṛṣṇa really prevent the Mahābhārata war? Did Kṛṣṇa classify the Kurukṣetra war as hiṁsā or ahiṁsā?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16109/1049) --- Your question might be good, but the underlying argument makes it opinion based. Anyways, you may not have to delete it. The system may auto delete, if the question remains 0 vote & not having answer 1+ vote.