# How was Krishna's wife Satyabhama related to Indra's mother Aditi?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, gods, bhagavata-purana

One of Krishna's most famous deeds is the killing of the demon Narakasura, which is the inspiration of the festival Deepavali.  Narakasura was tormenting the gods and had even stolen the earrings of Indra's mother Aditi, so Indra sought the help of Krishna.  As I discuss in this [question](http://vedabase.com/en/sb/10/59/2-3), Krishna rode on Garuda, accompanied by his wife Satyabhama, and defeated Narakasura.

But [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narakasura) claims that in addition to Indra reaching out  to Krishna, Indra's mother Aditi also approached Krishna's wife Satyabhama:

> All the Devas, led by Indra went to Vishnu, to ask him to deliver them from Narakasura. Vishnu promised them that he would attend to this matter, when he would be incarnated as Krishna. As promised to Mother Earth, Narakasura was allowed to enjoy a long reign. At last Vishnu was born as Krishna. **Aditi, who was a relative of Krishna's wife Satyabhama** (believed to be an Avatar of Bhudevi - Narakasura' mother), approached Satyabhama for help. When Satyabhama heard of the Narakasura's ill treatment of women and his behaviour with Aditi, she was enraged. Satyabhama approached Lord Krishna for permission to wage a war against Narakasura. As promised to the Devas and Aditi, Krishna attacked the great fortress of Narakasura, riding his mount Garuda with wife Satyabhama.

[This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=oMnsAAAAMAAJ&q=satyabhama%20aditi%20relative&dq=satyabhama%20aditi%20relative&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAmoVChMI9JbX7cznxgIViRkeCh3WZQYA) says the same thing:

> During a war he defeated Lord Indra and snatched away the magnificent earrings of Mother Goddess Aditi who was not only the ruler of Suraloka but also a **relative of Lord Krishna's wife, Satyabhama**.

My question is, is it true that Satyabhama was related to Aditi?

For those who don't know, Satyabhama was the daughter of Satrajit, a Yadava who obtained the famous Syamantaka gem after worshipping Surya the sun god.  Satrajit accused Krishna of stealing the gem, and when it was discovered that Krishna had nothing to do with it, Satrajit gave Krishna his daughter's hand in marriage.  In any case, [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp106.htm) of the Vishnu Purana describes the ancestry of Satrajit:

> The sons of Satwata were Bhajina, Bhajamána, Divya, Andhaka, Devávriddha, Mahábhoja, and Vrishńi.... Vrishńi had two sons, Sumitra and Yudhájit; from the former Anamitra and Śini were born.  The son of Anamitra was Nighna, who had two sons, Prasena and Satrájit. The divine Áditya, the sun, was the friend of the latter.

And for completeness [the previous chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp105.htm) describes how Satrajit's ancestor Satvata descended from Yadu, the founder of the Yadava race whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6772/36).

So I don't see how Satrajit was related to Aditi, who is the daughter of Brahma's son Daksha and the wife of the sage Kashyapa.  Is it possible that Satyabhama was related to Aditi on her mother's side?  Who was Satrajit's wife?  Also, Satyabhama was the incarnation of Vishnu's wife Bhumidevi, goddess of the Earth, so is it possible that Wikipedia is referring to Bhumidevi as the relative of Aditi?

Comment: It is possible that Wikipedia is making the Bhudevi-Aditi connection. Then again, how is Bhudevi related to Aditi?

Comment: Vaishnava Kanda Kartikamasa Mahatya of Skanda Purana has another version for previous birth of Satyabhama. Satyabhama was gunavati in her previous birth and She lost her father and husband just after marriage. Due to devotion they both go to Vishnuloka and her father was born as Satrajit. All attendants of Vishnu were born as Yadu people. As Gunavati did Kartika vrata all the time, she got the boon of marrying Vishnu (Krishna). So, soul of Satyabhama is mix of Bhudevi and Gunavati soul.