# Difference between different types of Gita (Uddhava-Gita, Rudra-Gita etc.)

Tags: bhagavad-gita, bhagavata-purana, uddhava-gita

Can someone please brief me the difference between Uddhava-Gita, Rudra-Gita, Bhikshu-Gita, Sruti-Gita, the Hamsa-Gita and the Bhagavad-Gita and also summarize what they talk about? I know about Bhagavad-Gita but not much about the other ones. These all are part of the Bhagavata Purana. If possible, please also redirect me to the exact places in Bhagavata Purana where each of these are mentioned.

Comment: GIta just means 'song' so to speak. Your question is too broad. You ought to break it up into separate questions for each one.

Comment: So are you only interested in Gitas found in the Srimad Bhagavatam, or Gitas found in other Puranas as well?  Because other texts contain a Shiva Gita, a Devi Gita, a Ganesha Gita, etc.

Comment: By the way, Uddhava Gita and the Hamsa Gita are the same thing.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, maybe my question gets broad by asking for difference between these. I actually wanted a brief up about the context of each of the Gitas. Like in what circumstances were they told and what did they mainly talk about( maybe a 1-2 liner can suffice).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan If possible, it would be nice to know about other Gita as well. Regarding Hamsa Gita and Uddhava Gita, I kind of knew they are same as read in wikipedia but had some confusion regarding whether it was a dialogue between Lord Krishna and Uddhava or it is told by Hamsa/Paramhansa. Btw. although wikipedia says they are same still in one sentence it says "The Gitas that find place in Srimad Bhagavata such as the Uddhava-Gita, the Rudra-Gita, the Bhikshu-Gita, the Sruti-Gita, the Hamsa-Gita propound Monism as the essence of their philosophy.", so that's why I asked for both.

Comment: The Uddhava Gita is a dialogue between Krishna and Uddhava, but as part of that dialogue Krishna tells the story of Vishnu taking the form of a swan in order to teach Brahma and the Sanatkumaras.  He also tells the story of Dattatreya teaching Yadu, which I discuss in my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6772/36

Comment: @Aby - Except Bagavad gita all are from Srimad bhagavatham. Rudra gita is instructions to prachetas( 10 sons of king Prachinabarhi) from Lord Shiva, it is contained in 24th chapter of 4th canto-about meditating on the God. Bhikshu gita is in 23rd chapter-11th canto by Sri krishna to Uddhava about control of mind through the story of bhikshu

Comment: Thanks Keshav and Vishu, This is the kind of answer I was expecting. I can find out more by reading through the Shrimad Bhagawatam. I just wanted the context and the place where they start so that I can reach there and read further.