# How many types of Gita spoken by Lord Krishna(Vishnu) himself?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, scripture, gita

Another Question Suddenly raised in my mind, I know that there is Bhagvad-Gita which is told by Lord Krishna. But I heard about other Gita which is told by lord krishna like Uddhav-Gita, So, Do you know the exact number of the Gita which is told by lord krishna him-self?

**Note:The Question is Different from this question: [Difference between different types of Gita (Uddhava-Gita, Rudra-Gita etc.)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10181/5)

Because, I want to know the Gita which is told by lord himself with name.**

So Please Share your idea with some valid resources like from Our Scriptures.
Thanks.

Comment: 'Gita' means a song. It is called 'Bhagavad geeta' since He sang it; it literally means 'Song of god'. are you looking for the scriptures or part of scriptures that is known by the name suffixed gita(ending with word 'Gita') and spoken by God? Or are you trying to find out how many times God spoke the knowledge to different people?

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande: yes, I am talking about the gita which was spoken by lord krishna himself. with name

Comment: UTTARA GITA must be included - delivered by KRISHNA

Comment: Offtopic: In the Siva gita Shiva shows Rama his roopram form.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The type of Gita spoken by Lord Krishna are:

#### 1) Bhagvad Gita-

> It is a 700 verse scripture from the Mahabharata adhyaaya 25 to 42(18 chapters) of Bhishmaparva between the Pandava Prince Arjuna and Lord Krishna who acts as his guide and charioteer.

#### 2) Anu Gita-

> Lord Krishna tells this Gita when Arjuna tells that he had forgotten Bhagvad Gita. It occurs in the Mahabharata in the Ashwamedha Parva. Adhyaaya 16. The conversation is between Pandava Prince Arjuna and Shri Krishna after the war and coronation of Yudhisthira as King.

#### 3) Hamsa Gita/ Uddhava Gita-

> It is in Shrimad Bhagavat Puran, Skandha 11,verse 40 section 6 to section 29 comprising of more than 1000 verses and consists of Krishna’s final discourse to Uddhava before Krishna leaves his mortal coil on Earth.

If you want by other incarnation of Vishnu as well then:

#### 1) Avadhutha Gita-

> It is based on the principles of Advaitha Vedanta and is said to have been sung by Lord Dattatreya who was considered an Avadhuta or a saint born on this earth beyond ego concsciousness and duality.

#### 2) Kapila Gita-

> It is from Shrimad Bhagavat Purana, Skandha 3, Chapters 23 to 33. It is the story of how Sage Kapila offers solace to his old mother Devahuti whose soul is hungering for spiritual knowledge.

#### 3) Rama Gita-

> It is from Adhyaatma Ramayan which is a part of Brahmanda Purana in the 5th Sarga of the Uttara Khanda which is the common Gita generally referred to.

#### 4) Vyasa Gita -

> It is from Kurma Purana, from 12th Adhyaaya onwards of Uttara Vibhaaga and Sage Vyaasa teaches the highest path to self knowledge. It emphasizes the unity of faiths and on the philosophy of non dualism.

*Refrences used from [here](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/vedic-knowledge/sacred-scriptures/gita/gita-its-various-kinds)*