# Mighty warriors in Mahabharata and Ramayana who were left handed

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, weapon, war

Can you give references of mighty warriors in the Mahabharata and the Ramayana who were left handed in using Bow & Arrow, Mace etc weapons in battlefield ?

Comment: [Related not Duplicate][Was Arjuna left-handed?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8615/3500)